# NSData category bug only without Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, bluetooth

I got a bug really magic (even though i don't believe that there is magic in the computer's world >< ), i will explain that with a long text, please have the pationce to read them all and help me out!!!!!

So i am working on an application who communicates with BLE peripheral, to write a command to the periheral, i use a method to convert the hex string to NSData, like this

```
+ (NSData *)dataWithHexString:(NSString *)hexString  
{  
   hexString = [hexString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];  
   NSMutableData * resultData= [[NSMutableData alloc] init];  
   unsigned char whole_byte;  
   char byte_chars[3] = {'\0','\0','\0'};  
   for (int i = 0; i < ([hexString length] / 2); i++) {  
      byte_chars[0] = [hexString characterAtIndex:i*2];  
      byte_chars[1] = [hexString characterAtIndex:i*2+1];  
      whole_byte = strtol(byte_chars, NULL, 16);  
      [resultData appendBytes:&whole_byte length:1];  
   }  
   return [NSData dataWithData:resultData];  
}
```

it is a NSData category method, which i found somewhere else in the net, the parameter (hexString) is supposed to be converted to a command which has 16 bytes, i need to send them one by one, and here comes the issue,

1. this class method (implemented by category) works well when i debug with Xcode (not the simulator but in the real iPhone),
2. this class method not works well some times (return 15 bytes, whichi supposed to be 16 bytes) when i launch the application without Xcode, for example, i send 3 commands, and check the return data from this method, the first is 16 bytes, the second is 16 bytes, and the third is 15 bytes, or sometimes the second is 15 bytes,
3. this class method works fine if i copy it ino my code context dirrectlly without using category implementation,
   P.S. if i add nslog in the category method, it will not be displayed when i launch it without xCode (in the device console log)

so, here are my questions...

1. is there a different, bewteen category method and nomal method?  why if i try to not use category, it works?
2. is there a different, bewteen debug with Xcode and launch without Xcode?
3. why the NSlog not show in that case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The best way to understand what is happening is to print the `hexString` variable as a debug information when the resulting data only is only 15 bytes.

Comment: there is no log is displayed in the category method